# Find the time lag between two series

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I'm trying to find the lag between two series. Suppose there is a variable temp2 whose value lags behind temp1 where the lag is not constant.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
    datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 09:00:00"), by = "1 hour"),
    temp1 = seq(30, 21, by = -1),
    temp2 = c(30, seq(30, 25, by = -1), seq(25, 23, by = -1))
)
```

I want to have an additional column "lag" equal to the lag between temp1 and temp2 so that the result looks like this:

```
dt <- data.table(
    datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 09:00:00"), by = "1 hour"),
    temp1 = seq(30, 21, by = -1),
    temp2 = c(30, seq(30, 25, by = -1), seq(25, 23, by = -1)),
    lag = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, NA, NA)
)
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Why in row 7 the lag value is 2? I think it should be 1. And why are the numbers of the last two rows are `NA`? I think they should be 2.

Comment: I was just trying to show that the lag may not be constant. In row 7 temp1 = 24 and temp2 doesn't reach this value until row 9. The last two rows I set as NA because temp2 doesn't reach the temp1 values (the series ends). Perhaps I can change the example to make it clearer.

Comment: Why not just `dt[, lag:= temp2 - temp1][]`. If not please elaborate a bit more on the relationship between the time dimension and the two values.

Comment: My example was too simplistic. There isn't an exact relationship between the two values across time. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Subtraction** If simple subtraction is sufficient then:

```
library(data.table)

dt[, lag := temp2 - temp1]
```

giving:

```
> dt
               datetime temp1 temp2 lag
 1: 2000-01-01 00:00:00    30    30   0
 2: 2000-01-01 01:00:00    29    30   1
 3: 2000-01-01 02:00:00    28    29   1
 4: 2000-01-01 03:00:00    27    28   1
 5: 2000-01-01 04:00:00    26    27   1
 6: 2000-01-01 05:00:00    25    26   1
 7: 2000-01-01 06:00:00    24    25   1
 8: 2000-01-01 07:00:00    23    25   2
 9: 2000-01-01 08:00:00    22    24   2
10: 2000-01-01 09:00:00    21    23   2
```

**2) dtw** Another possibility is dynamic time warping.  You may need to customize this with different arguments depending on what you want but for example try this:

```
library(data.table)
library(dtw)

fm <- dt[, dtw(temp1, temp2)]
dt[, lag := tapply(fm$index2 - fm$index1, fm$index1, min)]
```

giving:

```
> dt
               datetime temp1 temp2 lag
 1: 2000-01-01 00:00:00    30    30   0
 2: 2000-01-01 01:00:00    29    30   1
 3: 2000-01-01 02:00:00    28    29   1
 4: 2000-01-01 03:00:00    27    28   1
 5: 2000-01-01 04:00:00    26    27   1
 6: 2000-01-01 05:00:00    25    26   1
 7: 2000-01-01 06:00:00    24    25   2
 8: 2000-01-01 07:00:00    23    25   2
 9: 2000-01-01 08:00:00    22    24   1
10: 2000-01-01 09:00:00    21    23   0
```

**Note:** The `ccf` function maybe helpful here too.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm going to edit my question to show how I'm trying to solve it and to clarify my problem.